# Diablo 3 runs on integrated graphics, but gets stuck on dedicated graphics

Tags: diablo-iii, pc, graphics-card

I would like to play Diablo III, and I have installed it on my laptop with Windows 10. I have a computer with 2 graphic cards. The first one is a low quality Intel embedded with the motherboard, the other one is an AMD Radeon HD 5000.

I was asked to install Battle.net, so I did, as well as DirectX. I have also installed the newest AMD drivers.

- Using the integrated Intel GPU, the game runs, but at a really low quality.
- Using the AMD GPU, the game gets stuck at the opening. The screen turns black, and there is just a cursor and music.

Why does it run with the integrated Intel GPU, and what do I need to do to run it with the dedicated AMD GPU?

Comment: It must be driver related.

Comment: vote to leave open. Unless you can provide meta on an overall decision to exclude this type of question, hardware/driver problems relating to gaming should 100% be on topic. Furthermore, user is asking why Diablo 3 runs on a lower spec, but not on a higher spec. This is helpful to future visitors who might have similar issues.

Comment: The issue is definitely that there's something wrong with your Radeon drivers. Can you run other games on Radeon? It would help to test other games on the same engine, but Diablo has its own custom one.

Comment: Are you choosing the GPU to run the game on from context menu, or from Catalyst? I've had problems with Catalyst settings being ignored, context menu always worked, though.

Comment: You might want to disable the onboard video card unless you really need it.

Comment: After installing the drivers check to make sure the video card is running properly in the device manager. I had a similar problem after I built my PC, but all I needed to do was restart my computer to get it working. Not just turning it on and off but actually selecting to restart.

Comment: Agree with @JonathanDrapeau. Having both AMD and Intel graphics cards can easily confuse a system. Disable the onboard if at all possible and make sure the drivers are updated. AMD and Intel do not play well together.

Comment: Do you have any kind of screen sizing adjustments? Right click on your desktop and go to "Display" in the menu that pops up. Make sure the "size" of your UI is set to 100%.